# Eclipse not creating new .java file in New Project wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, wizard

OK, I have a really basic (read stupid) question. I am just beginning Java programming, and am using Eclipse 3.7.2. I have done a few beginning projects without any problems. All of a sudden, when I create a new project using the wizard, it is not creating the src/.java file. When I try to manually add it after creating the project, I end up getting some cryptic error messages.

1. I have re-followed several walk-throughs on project creation for clues as to any option I may have accidentally un-checked and no luck.
2. Googling the answer brings up results for more advanced problems that are unrelated.
3. I have combed the preferences, but nothing looks obvious, and
4. I have gone hunting for any user app data I could delete to force a clean slate.
5. I have even created a new instance of Eclipse to a different directory and still have the same result.
6. My son's instance, which is on the same computer still creates the .java file from the wizard. The only difference is that my instances have the Android SDK installed (I am trying to create basic Java projects and not Android projects).

I am at a loss, and have lost a lot of time trying to correct the situation. **What do I need to do to reenable the creation of a src/.java file in Eclipse?**

Screenshots (click on image for full size):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Go through the [eclipse tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html), will help.

Comment: What "cryptic error message" are you getting?  Also, make sure you are in the java perspective if you haven't already checked that.

Comment: Can you format your question and remove any irrelevant details? It will improve the chances of the question being answered.

Comment: I think all details are relevant to him, especially when you don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Jaguar- I had previously created several projects successfully. In addition, i did in fact follow several walk-throughs when the issue developed, assuming I had checked or unchecked an option accidentally. These have not resolved the issue at hand.

Comment: BlackVegetable- I did finally manage to create a new .java file for a project without any events. I think I messed myself up trying to declare the default package. This fix will do, but now that it's "broke" I still would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: "The" src/.java file? *What* Java file do you expect it to create when creating a new project? My Eclipse doesn't create any Java files when I create a new Java project because it has no idea what to create.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are choosing a java project from the right folder in the wizard. It sounds like it is creating an android java project, which is probably why your src folder is missing. See if there is a helloworld project under example projects too in the wizard, that may get you started too. Screenshot may help us. I want to see which project type you choose and which folder it is in.

Comment: I haven't messed with Wizard folders, but I assume its a folder where the sub-directory is the available choices in the new wizard menu, and it contains the templates. If that's the case, I have not messed with those (yet) as I am new. I also have not intentionally changed any preferences with default templates that I am aware of.

Comment: I dont mean you have changed them, but it asks you to choose the kind of project to create. Its possible there is a "Java Project" under the Java folder and one under Android. Make sure you choose Java Project from the Java folder in the wizard.

Comment: I am specifically choosing New Java Project, where Android is specifically listed as a collapsed folder several options below the Java Project option. Also, I updated the question above to include 2 screenshots which do not seem helpful at this point, but there they are.

Comment: Rephrase- I had been simply selecting New>Java Project, but also did New>Project... and selected Java project in the wizard with same results. I have also now verified that Eclipse and Java are not being blocked by firewall in case of loopback to server function (I know, just trying everything I can think of).

Comment: Make sure you are using the java viewing perspective. Its in one of the menus up top.

Comment: As mentioned to BlackWidow above, I have a workaround now. I was manually adding the .java file incorrectly. Anything else is for curiosity sake (My system is still "broke" and I want to "fix" it). My understanding is that Java perspective is the default in eclipse, which I haven't changed. I changed it to Java browsing and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing eclipse to point to a new workspace. That may drop the android settings. Under the file menu, choose switch workspace and pick a new location. Thats most likely why a new install did not fix it. That workspace may have android settings in it, so change to a new folder somewhere else to test it like c:\workspace2\

Here's a good tutorial I found that may help too.

[eclipse java project tutorial](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2006/cmsc132/EclipseTutorial/project.html)

Comment: When I created the new instance, it was to a new folder. I set the new default workspace to a subfolder in the new instance folder. In this case d:\eclipse with d:\eclipse\Workspace the old one had been c:\eclipse with a workspace of c:\eclipse\Workspace.

Comment: Normally a new java project does not contain a package or java file until you add one. It should just have the empty source folder basically. So now I'm wondering why it was creating a java file in the first place, unless you give it a class name in the wizard.

Comment: I tinkered with that. The class isn't part of the procedure I have used up until your mentioning it, so I don't know what or how that would change the outcome. I'm going to go ahead and consider this issue resolved, since I have a solution now. Thanks for your help, especially with a blisteringly newbie question.